Need help with a Laplace transform / probability theory question
Exercise 7.1 here:

For the first part, it's easy to see for n = 1 and I've  tried a few different things to get the integrals to match for n = 2 (and suspect the solution is some type of induction), but (assuming you can differentiate under the integral), you get an E[xf(x)] on one side which I dont know how to match with an E[f($X_1+X_2$)] on the other
For the second part, you can see that the expression in the limit is just E[f($S_n$)] where the X_i's in the $S_n$ have paramater $\frac{n}{y}$. It would be nice if you could say that as you some more X_is that approaches y almost surely (then continuity of f would probably give you the result), but I don't think that's what the strong law of large number says and I wasn't able to prove that myself.
Any help would be appreciated; thank you!
P.S book is Probability with Martingales by David Williams
